# How to implement angular validation for multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

Please check my work on plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/Jb43KPTXwF6zISS8PkaF?p=preview

Here I have two buttons save and modify. When I use save(type submit) button the form is validating before calling the function. Now I want to implement the same validation for modify(type button) button. So that when I click on it form should validate before calling the modify function.

Or if you have other solutions also i will take it forward for implementation but remember i need validation with multiple button on same form

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You could try this module http://jonsamwell.github.io/angular-auto-validate/ as it does what you want automatically without the need for you to write any complex code -this is a shameless plug as I wrote it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could move `scope.Modify()` into the directive. I think it's more semantic that way anyway. Then just return false so the form doesn't actually submit and run whatever submitting logic you want in there.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9gXowNY7ipxTRTA5piGY?p=preview)

```
                    scope.submit = function (event) {
                      submitController.setAttempted();
                      if (!scope.$$phase) scope.$apply();

                      if (!formController.$valid) return false;

                      scope.$apply(function() {
                          fn(scope, {$event:event});
                      });
                    }

                    formElement.bind('submit', scope.submit);

                    scope.Modify = function () {
                        // process scope.session
                        scope.submit();

                        alert('Modified!');

                        return false;
                    };
```

Comment: Hello Morgan, The solution you given will work only for modify button and if i need to add more button's i cant use this. and moreover if we use your solution tell me the way how could i implement logical part in controller as per your solution logical part is defined in directive which i dont want.

Comment: Simply move it into the controller. In the example, you'd have to rename `scope` to `$scope` to take advantage of DI. Because you never supplied a `scope` value for your directive's return object, it defaults to `false`, so you're actually sharing a scope between your directive and your controller. This method is typically not recommended for reusable components. The magic happens when you return `false` for the function which is called by clicking on the Modify button. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AiV87jUZJn98w4mbE2Xt?p=preview) / [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)